# How to copy junction points on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, robocopy, copying, junction-points

I have tried several different tools in order to be able to copy junction points on Windows XP but none of them copied the junction point as junction point. All programs I have tried so far are creating directories instead of junction points. I have tested RichCopy, SuperCopier and Robocopy from the W2k3 resource kit. I know that there is a new version of Robocopy which has the /SL option for symbolic links, but this version seems to be unavailable for XP. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the right tool. [FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) is able to copy correctly. It preserves the junction points and can also verify. Very useful to copy profiles. Great tool!